# Error when using "Calendar day(s)" option for subscriptions - "To create a schedule that runs on multiple days, you must choose which days to use."

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

Can someone explain the correct syntax for the Calender days option of SSRS scheduling? I am trying to set up a schedule for every day except the 1st of the month. I tried 2-31, "2-31" and also 2,3,4,5...,31 but all brought up the same error.

"To create a schedule that runs on multiple days, you must choose which days to use"

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I was trying to do every month all at once and the scheduler got cranky because as we all know 30 days hath September, April, June, and November. I ended up having to make three schedules, one for the 31 day months where 2-31 worked one for the 30 day months using 2-30 and one for poor February alone.

Comment: Don't forget the schedule for leap year, when February has 29 days.